# Refactor $(document).ready(), currently have 2 instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I've got following JavaScript functions but want to refactor the $(document).ready() as I've got 2 instance of it. How can I achieve this?

```
FlashMessenger = {
    init: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".flash").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(".flash").remove();
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
}

SelectLanguage = {
    init: function() {
        $('#selectLanguageId').change(function() {
            $('#frmSelectLanguage').submit();
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(FlashMessenger.init);
$(document).ready(SelectLanguage.init);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, there's no reason you *have* to combine them.

But if you want to:

```
$(document).ready(function(jq){
    FlashMessenger.init(jq);
    SelectLanguage.init(jq);
});
```

Breaking it down:

- Create a function to do all your init (it can be named or anonymous; the one above is anonymous).
- Have it *call* the other init functions, passing in the jQuery instance that jQuery passes you just in case they use it.

You might choose to wrap each `init` call in a `try/catch` block as well, so that errors in one init don't prevent the next init from occuring, but that depends on your needs.

Answer (score 8):

It’s perfectly acceptable to set multiple handlers for $(document).ready, although you may have a good reason to do otherwise that I’m not aware of. You might be interested in knowing that $(handler) can be used as shorthand for $(document).ready(handler):

```
$(FlashMessenger.init);
$(SelectLanguage.init);
```

If you really want them in one call though, try this:

```
$(function() {
    FlashMessenger.init();
    SelectLanguage.init();
});
```

Comment: Ugh, thank you for pointing that out. That was a little absent–minded of me. Edited.

Comment: @Skelton & Ben: The combined version is still failing to pass the argument jQuery passes into the function into the `init` functions. If they rely on it (which is common), they'll fail.

Comment: @JPot: True, in this case we can see that they don't. In the general case, though...

Answer (score 3):

Just combine them into one call with an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  FlashMessenger.init();
  SelectLanguage.init();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    FlashMessenger.init();
    SelectLanguage.init();
});
```

Comment: You're missing some `()` there (at least).

Comment: Almost, but not quite. You need to invoke the init functions with ().

Answer (score 1):

Option 1

```
FlashMessenger = {
    init: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".flash").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(".flash").remove();
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
}    
SelectLanguage = {
    init: function() {
        $('#selectLanguageId').change(function() {
            $('#frmSelectLanguage').submit();
        });
    }
}

$(function(){
    FlashMessenger.init();
    SelectLanguage.init();
});
```

Option 2

```
FlashMessenger = {
    init: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".flash").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(".flash").remove();
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
}

SelectLanguage = {
    init: function() {
        $('#selectLanguageId').change(function() {
            $('#frmSelectLanguage').submit();
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    FlashMessenger.init();
    SelectLanguage.init();
});
```

Option 3
You actually don't need those 2 objects since the only hold the init methods, so here's the ultimate solution, in my opinion, unless you use those objects elsewhere.

```
$(function(){
    $('#selectLanguageId').change(function() {
        $('#frmSelectLanguage').submit();
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".flash").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(".flash").remove();
        });
    }, 5000);
})
```

I prefer 2 and 3 for [this](http://encosia.com/2010/08/18/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/) reason.

Comment: You're missing some `()` there (at least). (Four people making the same mistake? Weird.)

Comment: To cite T.J. Crowder: "You are missing some `()` there Edit: Too late :)

Comment: @JPot: Still, weird that four separate people would make the same two mistakes. And so far, only a couple of them have fixed one of the mistakes and none of them has fixed the other.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Copy paste can be a b**** sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I think what the op is saying is, "If in the future I have a third function to be invoked at `document.ready`, then how do I do it without touching that piece of code?"

If you do not want multiple `$(document).ready()` calls, you could just create an array called `startupHooks` and add each method to it:

```
startupHooks[ startupHooks.length ] = myNewStartupHook;
```

and your startup script could look like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for( var i=0; i<startupHooks.length; i++ ) {
        startupHooks[i]();
    }
}
```

I know that is not mighty useful, but if that appeals to you, you can do it this way.

Personally, I'd go with multiple `$(document).ready()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd go for not using document.ready at all.
If you place the scripts at the end of your html-page(just before the  tag) you can just write in any way you like.
Maybe this doesn't work for 0.01% of the scripts but it never failed to work for me.

Positive effect of this is that the initial HTML+CSS rendering goes faster.
You can also read about it on yahoo. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom